# Is stochastic process a martingale?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Is the stochastic process

$$
X(t):=W\left(\int_0^t f(W(s))\mathrm{d}s\right)
$$
a martingale? Here, $f(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ is a positive function and $W(s)$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the process which you want to consider...? Do you perhaps mean $\int_0^t f(s) \, ds$ instead of $\int_0^t f(W_s) \, ds$...? If not, then why would you expect this process to be a martingale...?

Comment: Yes, I am sure I want to consider this ;) I have seen it in a few papers an I still don't get it as they never eloborate on this. (See for example this old question of myself on which you also wrote a comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884701/preservation-of-martingale-property-under-absolutely-continuous-monotone-time-ch?noredirect=1#comment5959863_2884701). Basically, a similar problem arises in all papers where the authors claim that the time changed BS model is equivalent to Heston's model.

Comment: In case of zero interest rates $r=0$ the Heston return process is $X(t) = \rho\int_0^t\sqrt{ \lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}W^1(s) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\int_0^t \sqrt{\lambda(s)}\mathrm{d}W^2(s)$ where $W^1$ and $W^2$ are independent Brownian motions and $\lambda(t)$ is the CIR process $\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)=\kappa(\theta-\lambda(t))\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\sqrt{\lambda(t)}\mathrm{d}W^1(t)$. Now it is often claimed that the dynamics of Heston are equivalent to $\rho W^1\left(T(t)\right)+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W^2(T(t))$ with $T(t)=\int_0^t\lambda(s)\mathrm{d}s$.

Comment: Now this equivalence would mean that the time changed arithmetic Brownian motion is indeed a martingale. And I dont see why this should be the case.

Comment: PS: I performed a Monte Carlo simulation and the empirical mean of the above process is always very close to zero as it should be for a martingale.

Comment: @lbf_1994 The empirical mean should always be close to zero for a martingale? That is news to me.

Comment: If it starts at zero, then this is the case. And my proposed "martingale" starts at zero

Comment: @lbf_1994 no it’s not... consider the prototypical martingale, a random walk starting from zero.

Comment: Yes it is. For a martingale the function $t\rightarrow\mathbb{E}[M(t)]$ is constant. Hence, $\mathbb{E}[M(t)]=\mathbb{E}[M(0)]=0$ if the martingale starts at zero. This is also the case for your random walk example. the random walk is a martingale if and only ifa single step size has mean zero.

Comment: That does not mean we expect the empirical mean to always, or even typically be close to zero. Here: try it out. Make ten one-million-step random walks and take their sample means. I just did three and got 481, -383, -826. If there’s mean reversion it isn’t a martingale.

Comment: By the strong law of large numbers the empirical mean tends to zero almost surely if I let the number of sample paths go to infinity. Secondly, could you elobrate on your comment regarding mean-reversion?

Comment: Oh so you’re talking about the distribution over many sample paths at a fixed $t$? When you said “the empirical mean always is close zero” I thought you meant the time average of a sample path is always close to zero. “Empirical mean” generally means the time average of the process (or more generally the sample mean of a relevant realization of something)

Comment: yes, I fixed a time $t$, computed trajectories of the process up to time $t$ and averaged them to get the mean of the process at that specific time $t$. I did that for several values of $t$ and always got results very, very close to zero.

Comment: Ok that makes sense then, sorry for the noise. I was just saying that being a martingale and being stationary are generally antithetical.

Comment: @lbf_1994 What do (or they) mean by "equivalent to"? Equal in distribution?

Comment: They do not further specify this unfortunately. See for example the first sentence in the penultimate paragraph on page 10 in the following document: https://www.fdic.gov/bank/analytical/cfr/2008/wp2008/tcmpapnew12.pdf.
In another document (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=283999) they say that the measure change with Radon-Nidodym derivative $\exp(i\rho W^1(T(t))+i\sqrt{1-\rho^2}W^2(T(t))+\frac{1}{2}T(t))$  transforms $W^1(t)$ to $W^1(t)-i\rho T(t)$, i.e. a variant of Girsanov theorem.